# Symfony/Doctrine: How does addJoinedEntityResult work for a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, native

i have the following problem. I guess it is misunderstanding. But after googling for hours without finding a solution i post it here.

I have a native query in Doctrine:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
        $rsm->addEntityResult('Acme\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment', 'c');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'comment_id', 'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'slug', 'slug');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'comment', 'comment');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'created', 'created');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Worker', 'w', 'c', 'komments');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('w', 'worker_id', 'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('w', 'worker_name', 'name');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Acme\CommentBundle\Entity\Document', 'd', 'c', 'documents');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'document_id', 'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('d', 'document_name', 'name');

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createNativeQuery('SELECT t.id, c.id AS comment_id, c.slug, c.created, c.comment, c.worker_id AS comment_worker_id, c.created AS comment_created, d.id AS document_id, d.name AS document_name, w.id AS worker_id, w.name AS worker_name
            FROM comment_thread t
            INNER JOIN project p ON p.comment_thread_id = t.id
            LEFT JOIN comment c ON t.id = c.thread_id
            INNER JOIN worker w ON c.worker_id = w.id
            LEFT JOIN comment_document d ON c.id = d.comment_id
            WHERE p.id = :project_id
            ORDER BY c.created ASC', $rsm)
            ->setParameter('project_id', $
```

Unfortunately the first addJoinedEntityResult (Worker) is not working. If i remove it the remaining addJoinedEntityResult (Document) is just perfect.

I guess this is because the Document is linked to the Comment. So the Comment is the "parent" of the Document.
In case of the Worker it is vice versa: The Comment is "child" of the Worker and not the "parent" like for the Document.

In other words:
- A worker can have multiple Comments
- A comment can have multiple Documents

My result set should have the Comment as base, with the (one) worker and the (0 .. n) documents associated.

But how do i set up this relationships in my Doctrine Result Mapping?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Nicki

Comment: Have you tried working directly with the Doctrine ORM by using a DQL query?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is what mapper rewrites "name" field when you attach second entity. had same situation and fixed it by renaming field in table and in entity mapping and in entity class so different entities/tables don't have same name properties/columns.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot see your entities, so I am not sure if this is any help, but it looks like you have a typo:

```
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Worker', 'w', 'c', 'komments');
```

should perhaps be

```
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Worker', 'w', 'c', 'comments');
```

(*komments* to *comments*)